# CopyFiles with webpack-encore

Tags: webpack-encore

i need to copy files from node_modules to a directory web/bundles/myBundle/components

But now i have an error : 
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/srv/project/web/bundles/myBundle/components'

```
Encore
  .setOutputPath('web/bundles/myBundle/')
  .setPublicPath('/bundles/myBundle')
  .addEntry('myBundle', './app.js')
  .copyFiles({
  from: './src/project/myBundle/Resources/public/components',
  to: 'components',
});
```

I just need to copy files, i tried that but i dont want to specify addEntry because there's none (empty js file just to solve problem).

If you have any idea or solution, thx !

Answer (score 2):

Change "to:" line to the following

```
to: 'components/[path][name].[ext]',
```

The elements in the square brackets are keywords that will be replaced with the real path/filename/extension of each file **during** the copy process

Answer (score 0):

**Final solution, and copy methods explanation (in Symfony project)**

for example you got custom website template, you copy its assets into Symfony PROJECT `assets/template-name/assets` as normal configuration for webpack files to add

[image: assets structure]

in `webpack.config.js`

```
    .copyFiles(
    { from: './assets/vuesy/assets/images',
                includeSubdirectories: true,
                to: 'assets/images/[folder]/[name].[ext]',
                context: 'assets/vuesy/assets/',
                pattern: /.*/
    }
)
```

and here is HOW to build proper folder structure in your `public/build` directory.

[image: folder building rules]

1. `from:` - `is the place where files are - relative to - webpack.config.js`, dont put `/` at the end but dont forget to use `./` at the begining (in this case assets folder is in the same directory as webpack.config.js)
2. `to:` your `public/build` is defined, from this place you starting build `directory` structure, add for example `assets/images` then use `[folder]` KEY, add `/` and tell what will be name for final file `[name].[ext]`

you can add own name for file by adding `[myownname-foo-v1-][name]` in this part. It generate `myownname-foo-v1-realfilename.extension`

3. `context:` - context is a place FROM WHERE you start digging and copying files..