# Encore Webpack - Copy folders structure with copy-webpack-plugin

Tags: symfony, webpack-encore, copy-webpack-plugin

I'm using Symfony 5 and copy-webpack-plugin. I would like copy this structure from assets/fonts to public/build/fonts :

assets
----fonts
--------folder1
------------subFolder1.1
----------------file1.1.1
----------------file1.1.2
------------file1.2
------------file1.3
--------folder2
------------subFolder2.1
----------------file2.1.1
----------------file2.1.2
------------file2.2
------------file2.3
--------file3
--------file4

I have this webpack configuration :

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

```
.addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin(
    [{
        patterns: [{

            from: '**/*.*',
            to: 'fonts',
            context: './fonts',
            force: true

        }]
    }], 
    {
        copyUnmodified: true
    }
))
```

However, it doesn't work. I tried a lot of different configurations, to no avail.

Comment: here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472078/copyfiles-with-webpack-encore/72959857#72959857